# How I can send a email with attachments in Camunda?

Tags: email, attachment, send, camunda

I am new here and also using the Camunda application, my question is that when I try to send an email with Camunda's own extension ( camunda-bpm-mail ) I don't see that I have the option to send attachments along with the email and I would like to know if there is a way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camunda-bpm-mail component supports attachments. See:

https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-platform-7-mail/blob/6470b1351818d90b61d941fe05b1205e14a637a4/extension/core/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/extension/mail/send/SendMailRequest.java#L40

https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-platform-7-mail/blob/6470b1351818d90b61d941fe05b1205e14a637a4/extension/core/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/extension/mail/send/SendMailConnector.java#L121

and includes an example;
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-platform-7-mail/tree/main/examples/print-service/src/main/resources

[image]